# Некоректный путь по gps в Android-приложении

Tags: геолокация, android, java, алгоритм, gps

Привет всем!

У меня следующая проблема: я разрабатываю приложение для Android, и мне нужно строить путь по gps-координатам. Но после испытаний данного приложения выяснилось, что координаты сильно прыгают, когда даже я стою, они прыгают (до 30 метров).

Есть ли какие-то алгоритмы, которые могут определить состояния, стою я или иду, и которые будут апроксимировать новую координату относительно старой?

Comment: Можно использовать другие сенсоры, например, акселерометр, для определения состояния телефона.

Comment: А можно ещё посмотреть на библиотеку от гугла для [сглаживания пути](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143205/).